# Access local network from VPN while in local network

Tags: networking, ssh, vpn, private-network

My local network contains the following setup:

- Windows
- RPI (WireGuard, Nginx)
- NAS

When I tried connecting to the VPN from an outside network I could ssh into the local machines without an issue (which I guessed meant I setup the VPN properly, as local machines are in 192.168 and VPN ones in 10.6).

Later, when I came back home, I used the Windows to ssh into the RPI and adjust the Nginx config. I wanted to test whether the adjustments I made worked while connected to the VPN, so I figured I could connect to the VPN from the Windows (which is on the local network) and try it out. Surprisignly (to me), it didn't work: I could ssh into the RPI using the VPN IP but not the local one.

At first I thought that could be expected behaviour, but then I tried doing the same from WSL (in the Windows) and that worked. I was able to connect to the RPI both with 192.168 and 10.6. Then I tried the phone, and I also could ssh with 192.168 and 10.6.

### Configs

###### RPI `ip route`

```sh
default via 192.168.0.1 dev eth0 src 192.168.0.96 metric 202
10.6.0.0/24 dev wg0 proto kernel scope link src 10.6.0.1
... # docker1
... # docker2
192.168.0.0/24 dev eth0 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.0.96 metric 202
```

###### RPI `wg0.conf`

```sh
[Interface]
PrivateKye = ...
Address = 10.6.0.1/24
ListenPort = ...
[Peer]
PublicKey = ...
PreSharedKey = ...
AllowedIPs = 10.6.0.5/32
```

###### Windows `wireguard config file`

```sh
[Interface]
PrivateKey = ...
Address = 10.6.0.5/24
DNS = 10.6.0.1

[Peer]
PublicKey = ...
PresharedKey = ...
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0, ::/0
Endpoint = ...
```

Can anybody elaborate why this happens and if there's a "fix"? Currently I wonder whether it's a Windows-only behaviour.

Comment: Server and peer configs would be needed - ensure `AllowedIPs` is set and there's no route conflicts with the WireGuard IP Subnet

Comment: Added the wireguard server and client config, and also the RPI's `ip route`. Would it be useful to post Windows' `route print` as well? If so, what part? It's quite long.